# error: void value not ignored as it ought to be and error:return statement with a value

Tags: c++

I'm working on a short code for my programming class and I can't figure out how to fix these two errors: "void value not ignored as it ought to be" and "return statement with a value, in function returning 'void'[ - f-permissive ]"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void FutureValue(double, double);
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    //Declare variables
    int amount;
    int newAmount;
    int interestRate;

    cout << "Please enter the dollar amount. " << endl;
    cin >> amount;

    cout << "Please enter the interest rate(e.g., nine percet should be entered as 9.0)." << endl;
    cin >> interestRate;

    newAmount = FutureValue(amount,interestRate);

    cout << "The new dollar amount is" << newAmount << endl;

    return 0;
}

void FutureValue(double initialAmount, double interestRate)
{

    //Declare variables
    double finalAmount;

    finalAmount = ( 1 + interestRate/100) * initialAmount;

    return(finalAmount);
}
```

The first error was indicated to be on line 42, where newAmount is. The second one is on line 57, where return(FinalAmount) is.

Any help regarding this issue is very welcome!

Comment: What part of "return statement with a value, in function returning 'void'" do you not understand? You probably wanted to return double, not void, in FutureValue.

Answer (score 1):

The following line in `FutureValue` is not right since the return type of the function is `void`.

```
 return(finalAmount);
```

Also, the line

```
 newAmount = FutureValue(amount,interestRate);
```

in `main` is not right due to the same reason -- the return type of the function is `void`.

Change the return type of the function to `double`.

```
double FutureValue(double initialAmount, double interestRate)
{
   //Declare variables
   double finalAmount;

   finalAmount = ( 1 + interestRate/100) * initialAmount;

   return(finalAmount);
}
```

It can be simplified to:

```
double FutureValue(double initialAmount, double interestRate)
{
   return ( 1 + interestRate/100) * initialAmount;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I changed the return type to double in that portion and also in the beginning of the code, which made it work!